# What does HHJ stand for?

Tags: legal-terms

I have seen many explanatory materials of judicial titles recommend this abbreviation to be used in certain contexts, but none which explain what it is itself short for. What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HHJ stands for [Her Honour Judge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honour_(style)) or [His Honour Judge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honour_(style)). See an example usage [here](https://www.nuffieldfjo.org.uk/events/in-conversation-with-hhj-carole-burgher):

> Join us as we talk to Her Honour Judge (HHJ) Carole Burgher about...

Comment: So then is it only used to refer to judges in the 3rd person?